# Tone.js FFT keeps getting negative infinity values

Tags: javascript, tone.js

I've been trying to get values for the fft using Tone.js. I want to get values of the note that was played using this function

```
async function playCasio(noteToPlay, duration) {
    Tone.start()

    // Create an FFT component
    const fft = new Tone.FFT(1024)

    const casio = new Tone.Sampler({
        urls: {
            A1: "A1.mp3",
            A2: "A2.mp3",
        },
        baseUrl: "https://tonejs.github.io/audio/casio/",
    })
    
    const tones = await Tone.loaded();
    
    // Connect the Casio sampler to the FFT
    casio.chain(fft, Tone.Destination)

   
    casio.triggerAttackRelease(noteToPlay, duration);

   
    const fftValues = fft.getValue();

    console.log(fftValues);
}
```

However, when I look at the console log, it says this
[screenshot of console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7kKV.png)

meaning fft is listening for silence (-Infinity db).
It does play the right sound, and I can hear it.
I could not find the solution.
How can I achieve this? I just want some values to display other than -Infinity

I've tried to connect casio to destination, tried to use promise so that it waits till the note is played.

Comment: I think you need to use a `setTimeout` for some period of time and then `fft.getValue` ... as it is, you'd be getting the fftValues immediately, probably before any sound is able to play - perhaps wait `duration` amount of time (if it can be easily converted to milliseconds)